# C# Program - The Login Is from an untrusted domain name and cannot be used with windows authentication

Tags: c#

I have been using a C# program, which I wrote several years ago, that accesses data from a SQL Server (2008 R2). Recently the screen on my laptop malfunctioned and the cost of replacing it was too expensive so I decided to transfer the C# program and the database to my desktop computer. Visual Studio 2010 was perfect. So as to not change anything I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 and attached the database. So far so good. Using SQL Server I can access the database, no problem, but as soon as I run the C# program, which also runs just fine, until it tries to access the "mdf" file, then I get the "The Login is from an untrusted domain...." error message.

I have tried deleting the log file and re-attaching the mdf file, as was suggested by someone, but that didn't work.

So any suggestions anyone?

Comment: Did you verified credentials for connections used to connect database, i.e machine name p,username & password

Comment: The computer names are different, the PC is Joe-PC and the laptop is Joe-HP. The laptop has a username/password the PC does not.

Comment: which SQL Engine you are using, I mean SQLExpress or SQL Server ?

Comment: SQL Express. I'm also using LINQ in C# to access the database, if that is any help.

Comment: Can you post code in which you are making connection  (i,e. using DataContext)

Comment: This is the code where the message appears  var donor1 = (from d in dfrDataContext.Donors
                              where d.DonorNumber == donorString
                              select d).FirstOrDefault();